# Prove that $S$ is the number of integers congruent to $n$ mod $p$ between $a$ and $b$ inclusive where $a,b$ are integers

Tags: modular-arithmetic

This question has already been answered on another question although the answers are not correct. However, thanks to the comments, I was able to find a formula. Here it is:

$T=n-a+p\lfloor\frac{b-n}{p}\rfloor$

$S =\lfloor\frac{T}{p}\rfloor+1$

So we have to prove how $S$ is this formula.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just do  it.  If $a \le kp+n$ so that $kp + n$ is the first such integer and $mp+ n \le b$ is the last such digit and $kp+n, (k+1)p + n,....., (m-1)p+n, mp+n$ are all of them... then how many are there.

Comment: Well, there's m-k+1 integers

Comment: So I think I have a good lead right now! Thanks to your argument, S = m+k+1, which explains the 1, but in simplifying I learn that k = floor((n-a)/p) and m = floor((b-n)/p). But why is that?

Comment: Ah ok I just understood thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof isn't as hard as it looks.

Let $kp+n$ , where $k,n,p$ are integers, the first integer in the interval $a,b$ congruent to ${n}\pmod p$ and $sp+n$, where $s$ is also integer,the last integer in the interval.
There is $s-k+1$ integers in the interval $a,b$ congruent to ${n}\pmod p$.

Let's go on :

$(k-1)p+n\lt a\le kp+n\Rightarrow (k-1)p\lt a-n\le kp\Rightarrow k-1\lt \frac{a-n}{p}\le k$

$\Rightarrow -k+1\gt \frac{n-a}{p}\ge -k$

However $-k$ is an integer so $\lfloor \frac{n-a}{p}\rfloor = -k$

Let's continue with $b$ :

$sp+n\le b\lt (s+1)p+n\Rightarrow sp\le b-n\lt (s+1)p\Rightarrow s\le \frac{b-n}{p}\lt s+1$

However $s$ is an integer so $\lfloor \frac{b-n}{p}\rfloor = s$

But we know there is $s-k+1$ integers in the interval $a,b$ congruent to ${n}\pmod p$ so there is $\lfloor \frac{b-n}{p}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{n-a}{p}\rfloor + 1$ integers in this interval.